# Strange behavior of PHP in a Symfony2 repository

Tags: php, symfony, repository, entity

Something really special happened with my code.

Here is my repository function :

```
public function getPlace($id, $lang = 'fr') {

        $this->setDefaultLocale($lang);

        // ... etc, etc
}
```

I call this function like that :

```
$place = $myRepo->getPlace($id, 'en');
```

In my repository, the local is still 'fr'...

When I print the $lang variable, 'en' is display.

If you use this code, in static, it works perfectly :

```
public function getPlace($id, $lang = 'fr') {

        $this->setDefaultLocale('en');

        // ... etc, etc
}
```

I can't understand why... I tried basic things like :

```
public function getPlace($id, $lang = 'fr') { //(NOT WORKING)

        $t = ($lang == 'fr') ? 'fr' : 'en';
        $this->setDefaultLocale($t);

        // ... etc, etc
}



public function getPlace($id, $lang = 'fr') { // (WORKING)

        $t = 'en';
        $this->setDefaultLocale($t);

        // ... etc, etc
}
```

I can't figure out...

Thanks a lot,

Gabriel

Answer (score 0):

After further research, I found the problem.

I call this repository function twice. The first was in french, then, the second kept the defaultLocale 'fr' and the 'en' didn't change anything...

So, here is another question : do you know why, when I set the defaultLocale of my repository once, I can't change it another time ?

Thanks